# RES memory in TOP increases but no brk/mmap hit

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

We see a strange behavior where the top output indicates that sporadically RES memory increased by 264KB multiple times over a period of 52 hours. There is no periodicity to the increase. We tried runnning gdb with breakpoint in brk/mmap, however none of them were hit.
We tried heap profile tool at https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/heapprofile.html, however again the heap dump revealed no new memory allocations by the process over the slot of time when memory increased.
No new swap memory was consumed, how do we explain this behaviour ?

tried breakpoint, and heap profilling tools, however to no luck.